# Issue in fetching the required field using regex in pig

Tags: apache-pig

The log file is as follows  :

$4 : processName="ManageBillingAccountAssociations_V1.getSharedAccountDetails"

l= foreach b generate REGEX_EXTRACT($4,'(.*[^a-z])',1);

I am trying to fetch the "ManageBillingAccountAssociations_V1.getSharedAccountDetails"

but I am getting the output as:
processName="ManageBillingAccountAssociations_V1.getSharedAccountDetails"

please help me..

Comment: if you want to get the string after the equal to sign , you should use /=(.+)/ this as the regexp

Comment: REGEX_EXTRACT(string,regex,index)

 $4 contains the string :   (processName="ManageBillingAccountAssociations_V1.getSharedAccountDetails")
string is stored in $4,
I need to apply regex to $4 where i need the string ManageBillingAccountAssociations_V1.getSharedAccountDetails

I am Using the below command but I am getting the entire string as output :>(processName="ManageBillingAccountAssociations_V1.getSharedAccountDetails")

l= foreach b generate REGEX_EXTRACT($4,'(.*[a-z])',1);

Comment: Because the complete string satisfy the regular expression given use REGEX_EXTRACT($4,/=(.+)/,1) instead

Comment: I tried but i am getting output as ()

Comment: B = FOREACH a GENERATE REGEX_EXTRACT(col,'=.*$',0);
this worked for me, you can substring the output to remove the = at start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The regexp is satisfied by the complete string, you can instead do a,

```
 B = FOREACH a GENERATE REGEX_EXTRACT(col,'=.*$',0);
```

you can substring the output to remove the = at start by

```
 B = FOREACH a GENERATE SUBSTRING(REGEX_EXTRACT(col,'=.*$',0),1,(int)SIZE(REGEX_EXTRACT(col,'=.*$',0)));
```

Comment: Hi, Substring(string,startindex,stopindex) ,I understood how the substring works,Inbetween the start and stop index I need to get the string ,but in the above example  output is stored in B.

Comment: Could you please help me how to use substring here.

Comment: Hi,$3 :  layerName="OSB" .  I used b1 = foreach b generate SUBSTRING($3,10,15); n I got the output as "OSB" , But how to apply it on regex..Please help me..

Comment: B = FOREACH a GENERATE SUBSTRING(REGEX_EXTRACT(col,'=.*$',0),1,(int)SIZE(REGEX_EXTRACT(col,'=.*$',0)));

Comment: Thank you very much .. its working.. I tried          l= foreach b generate SUBSTRING(REGEX_EXTRACT($4,'=(.*)',1),1,5);